# Why result of IQueryable type converts to empty object?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAllCollections(CollectionsDTO collectionsDTO)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();

            try
            {
                var collectionsSectionRolesFlatDTO = (from c in db.Collections
                                                      join sr in db.SectionRole
                                                      on c.SectionRoleId equals sr.Id
                                                      select new CollectionsSectionRolesFlatDTO
                                                      {
                                                          Collections = new CollectionsDTO
                                                          {
                                                              CollectionTitleAr = c.CollectionTitleAr,
                                                              CollectionTitleEn = c.CollectionTitleEn,
                                                              CoverImagePath = c.CoverImagePath,
                                                              SectionRoleId = c.SectionRoleId,
                                                          },
                                                          SectionRole = new SectionRoleDto
                                                          {
                                                              NameAr = sr.NameAr,
                                                              NameEn = sr.NameEn
                                                          }
                                                      })
                                                      .AsQueryable();

                var collectionsDto = Mapper.Map<List<CollectionsSectionRolesDTO>>(collectionsSectionRolesFlatDTO);

                return Ok(collectionsDto);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("GetAllCollection: "+ ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

DTOs:

```
public class CollectionsDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CollectionTitleEn { get; set; }
        public string CollectionTitleAr { get; set; }
        public string CoverImagePath { get; set; }
        public int? SectionRoleId { get; set; }

    }

    public class CollectionsSectionRolesFlatDTO
    {
       public SectionRoleDto SectionRole { get; set; }
       public CollectionsDTO Collections { get; set; }
    }

    public class CollectionsSectionRolesDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CollectionTitleEn { get; set; }
        public string CollectionTitleAr { get; set; }
        public string CoverImagePath { get; set; }
        public int? SectionRoleId { get; set; }

        //section role
        public string NameAr { get; set; }
        public string NameEn { get; set; }

    }

public class SectionRoleDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string NameEn { get; set; }

    public string NameAr { get; set; } 
}
```

Automapper:

```
   CreateMap<Collections, CollectionsDTO>();
   CreateMap<CollectionsSectionRolesFlatDTO, CollectionsSectionRolesDTO>();
```

Now the problem is mindboggling.

this line

```
var collectionsDto = Mapper.Map<List<CollectionsSectionRolesDTO>>(collectionsSectionRolesFlatDTO);
```

is supposed to return the data but instead it returns what I have passed in the function `param`.

Why is this happening? I have spent literally hours but nothing. I checked all the automapper setting but this doesn't work.

I am new to c# so any help regarding it would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: have you configured the mapper? I think that is what is missing [see](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html)

Comment: You should use `ProjectTo` instead of `Map`. See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you be going through the trouble of double projection? Just configure Automapper with the information to get a desired DTO out of the object graph. Ensure you have navigation properties set up for your relationships to make querying against the object graph a lot simpler. Linq & EF does not need to be written as a substitute for SQL. (explicit joins) Navigation properties allow EF to provide those joins entirely behind the scenes for simpler querying.

First, the mapping:

```
CreateMap<Collections, CollectionsSectionRolesDTO>()
    // Id, NameAr, and NameEn should auto-resolve.
    .ForMember(x => x.CollectionTitleEn, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Collection.CollectionTitleEn))
    .ForMember(x => x.CollectionTitleAr, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Collection.CollectionTitleAr));
    // Continue for fields coming from Collection...
```

then to query using the automapper config. (config)

```
var results = db.Collections
     .ProjectTo<CollectionsSectionRolesDTO>(config)
     .ToList();
```

Done and dusted. No need to select and flatten data first into memory then use Automapper to create a new in-memory collection of the desired view model. Just project down to the desired view model directly within the query.

Double-projection is useful where you need to flatten data down first in order to perform conversions or transforms that cannot be converted in SQL. The first projection (`Select`) would typically be to an anonymous type or a DTO using ProjectTo, then fed into code that would provide the necessary transformations to produce the end result view models/DTOs.